# How can I make a program loop back to the start if else is true? C#

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, restart

Couldn't find any other answer on the site that covers this. If else is run and an error message is displayed, is it possible to restart the program by looping back to the start instead of restarting the console?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int User;
        int Array;
        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("C://log.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Input an number between 1 and 100");
        User = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (User < 101 && User > 0)
        {
            for (Array = 1; Array <= User; Array++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Array + ", " + Array * 10 * Array);
                outfile.WriteLine(Array + ", " + Array * 10 * Array);
            }
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit The Console");
                outfile.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you input an invalid number. ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }
}
```

Sorry! To be more clear I need to make the Program start again if the user inputs an invalid number

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would you want to? It seems that if it were to error, the state of the data would cause it to fail every time.

Comment: You need to separate your actual "working" code into its own function, then when you want to perform that operation you just call the function.

Comment: why not use a while loop. while(true) get the number and if valid, write console/out else continue

Comment: You should really throw that streamwriter into a using block. Not all paths close the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is placing your code inside a while loop, so that the code keeps repeating. The only way to *exit* the loop would be for the condition you just set in the `if` clause to be true. So something along the lines of:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int User;
        int Array;
        bool isUserWrong = true;  //This is a flag that we will use to control the flow of the loop
        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("C://log.txt");

        while(isUserWrong)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input an number between 1 and 100");
            User = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (User < 101 && User > 0)
            {
                for (Array = 1; Array <= User; Array++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Array + ", " + Array * 10 * Array);
                    outfile.WriteLine(Array + ", " + Array * 10 * Array);
                }
                isUserWrong = false; // We signal that we may now leave the loop
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry you input an invalid number. ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                //Note that here we keep the value of the flag 'true' so the loop continues
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit The Console");
        outfile.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this instead

```
User = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (User >= 101 || User <= 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry you input an invalid number. ");
    User = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```