# C# Play Again Number Game

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to implement the ability for the user to input Y or N to play the game again or exit, but I'm struggling to get my head round it without a massive rewrite of the code logic... I'm just getting back into C# today and am a beginner so please go easy on me :) I've already got the userContinue string ready and just want to enter a simple way of repeating the game and adding on ways of keeping score (slowly improving the game)

```
    using System;

namespace Guess_Number_V2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {
                PlayGame();
                Console.WriteLine("Would you play to play again? Y or N");
            } while (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y");

        }

        public static voic PlayGame()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randNum = rand.Next(1, 11);
            int incorrectGuesses = 0;
            int userScore = 10;
            int userGuess;
            int perGuess = 1;
            string userContinue;
            bool correctGuess = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10\nScore starts at 10, one point will be deducted with each incorrect guess.");

            userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (correctGuess == false)
            {
                if (userGuess == randNum)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess was right, the number was {0}! Total score is {1} and you had {2} incorrect guesses.", randNum, userScore, incorrectGuesses);
                    correctGuess = true;
                }

                if (userGuess > randNum)
                {
                    userScore -= perGuess;
                    incorrectGuesses++;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to high!");

                    correctGuess = false;
                }

                else if (userGuess < randNum)
                {
                    userScore -= perGuess;
                    incorrectGuesses++;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to low!");

                    correctGuess = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a program loop back to the start if else is true? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775020/how-can-i-make-a-program-loop-back-to-the-start-if-else-is-true-c-sharp)

Comment: Only a bit, the logic isn't working for me sadly

Comment: This code reads the user input only once before the loop instead of as first statement inside the loop. Therefore the loop never stops and never reads user input when the first guess was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you put your game logic in its own method. Say `PlayGame()`. Then you can simply write:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do {
        PlayGame();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you play to play again? Y or N");
    } while (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y");
}
```

Also, you can simplify your logic if you make an "infinite" loop and break out of it with `break;` when the guess is correct.

You can read and parse the user input at the beginning of each loop.

Setting the user score the number of incorrect guesses and the red console color can be done only once also.

Tested and working code:

```
using System;

namespace Guess_Number_V2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do {
                PlayGame();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("Would you play to play again? Y or N");
            } while (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y");
        }

        private static void PlayGame()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randNum = rand.Next(1, 11);
            int incorrectGuesses = 0;
            int userScore = 10;
            int userGuess;
            int perGuess = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10\nScore starts at 10, one point will be deducted with each incorrect guess.");

            while (true) {
                userGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (userGuess == randNum) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess was right, the number was {0}! Total score is {1} and you had {2} incorrect guesses.", randNum, userScore, incorrectGuesses);
                    break;
                }
                userScore -= perGuess;
                incorrectGuesses++;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                if (userGuess > randNum) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to high!");
                } else { // Must be userGuess < randNum
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong guess again, to low!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that but sadly when I guess the correct number it just says press anything to continue and the console app exits. I updates my code to have it in it's own method.
EDIT: Oh very nice I must say, what if I wished to carry over the users score and add it up over each repeated game. I would simply make the score variables global and update them?

Comment: Since we are using a do-while loop that reads the console after every game, the application cannot just exit when a game is finished.

Comment: Fixed it it compiles but the same issue applied, I even put a breakpoint on the do while loop it doesnt seem to reach the while console readline bit of the program...

Comment: Sadly same issue with your code won't let me press Y to continue, simply says
Press any key to continue...

And when I press a key it quits, I know whats wrong but I can't figure it out

Comment: My code never prints out "Press any key to continue...", so you must be running the wrong project. Every project must contain only one `Main` method. If your solution contains several projects, make sure to select the right one in visual studio. Right click on the project and select "Set as StartUp Project"

Comment: Ah okay I had debug on, I stopped running it accidentally in debug now it just exits automatically when I guess the correct number